# Whatsapp Crashes in Windows phone

Tags: whatsapp, nokia-lumia-630

i have Lumia 630, and i have a problem that whenever i press back key to go the main list of chats from a private chat, it crashes. it was not there until yesterday and i have no idea what caused it. please help me.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the app itself, not the Windows OS. There is a veritable multitude of possibilities for why it is crashing, which the app developers could really help you with better than we can here. I suggest that you get in touch with them.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty much a RAM usage issue. I once got that problem on my 520, which has 512 MB of RAM, just as your 630.

So, restart your phone, open WhatsApp, leave it for at least 30 seconds, let the messages be up to date, then start using. Using WhatsApp immediately after opening it causes it to crash sometimes.

Comment: Please refrain from reverting constructive edits that improve the formatting, grammar or readability of your post. Note that Stack Exchange sites are collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. For more information, see [this article in our Help Center](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/editing). Thank you!